# What Aud field indicates in JWT Token?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt

Hi I have SPA application and .Net core web API. I have registered two applications in azure AD. Below is my adal config in react app.

```
   /* istanbul ignore file */
import { adalGetToken, AuthenticationContext, UserInfo } from 'react-adal';
import { UserProfile } from '../common/models/userProfile';
class AdalContext {
    private authContext: AuthenticationContext | any;
    private appId: string = '';

    public initializeAdal(adalConfig: any) {
        this.authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);
        this.appId = adalConfig.clientId;
    }
    get AuthContext() {
        return this.authContext;
    }

    public getToken(): Promise<string | void | null> {
        return adalGetToken(this.authContext, this.appId).catch((error: any) => {
            if (error.msg === 'login_required' || error.msg === 'interaction_required') {
                this.authContext.login();
            }
        });
    }

    public acquireToken(callback: Function) {
        let user = this.AuthContext.getCachedUser();
        if (user) {
            this.authContext.config.extraQueryParameter = 'login_hint=' + (user.profile.upn || user.userName);
        }

        adalGetToken(this.authContext, this.appId).then(
            (token) => {
                callback(token);
            },
            (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    if (error.msg === 'login_required') this.authContext.login();
                    else {
                        console.log(error);
                        alert(error);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }

    public getCachedToken(): string {
        return this.authContext.getCachedToken(this.authContext.config.clientId);
    }
    public getCachedUser(): UserInfo {
        return this.authContext.getCachedUser();
    }

    public getUserProfileData(): UserProfile {
        const user = this.authContext.getCachedUser();
        const userProfileData = new UserProfile();
        if (user) {
            userProfileData.name = user.profile.name;
            userProfileData.firstName = user.profile.given_name;
            userProfileData.surname = user.profile.family_name;
            userProfileData.emailAddress = user.userName;
            userProfileData.userProfileName = user.profile.name || user.userName;
        }
        return userProfileData;
    }

    public logOut() {
        this.authContext.logOut();
    }
}

const adalContext: AdalContext = new AdalContext();
export default adalContext;
export const getToken = () => adalContext.getToken();
```

I am able to redirect to Azure AD and able to get token. I token first there is Aud field which has value of client id of azure ad app registered for Front End SPA app.

Below is my code for validating code in .Net core API.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.Authority = $"{authSettingsWebAPI.Instance}/{authSettingsWebAPI.TenantId}";
                options.Audience = azureAuthSettings.ClientId; //client id of Azure AD front end SPA APP
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidateActor = false,
                };
            });
```

My Aud field has vale client id of SPA app. I am bit confused here.

> Aud should be value of SPA app registered in azure AD or client id of
> Web API app registered in azuure AD?

The point here I am confused because I have third App(I would call it Protected API) recently came where my API calls another web API app(Protected API) and I want to have authentication from web API app to protected api app using on behalf of flow.

When we want to implement on behalf of flow I will have url like below

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
&client_id={client_id of Web API Gateway application}
&client_secret={client_secret}
&assertion={access token from previous step}
&scope={permission for Protected API application}
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
```

In above url assertion is 1st token I received for SPA and client id is my API app client id. If I pass api app client id and token received from SPA then It gives me error

Azure AD image

Client ID and Aud value in token should be same but In aud I am getting value of client id for SPA application. Can someone help me to understand Aud field I am receiving in token is proper or above url I am framing in wrong way? Can someone help me regarding this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you
Below is my configurations for ToDoListAPI API Permission

[image: TodoListAPI]

Below is configurations for ToDoListAPI Expose API
[image: API Expose API]

Below is configurations for SPA

[image: Configurations for SPA]

Postman

[image: postman]

Comment: `Aud` in first access token should be client id of Web API app.

Comment: Hi Allen Thanks for clarification. I had strong doubt and you cleared. But Why I am getting SPA app client id in Aud? Any configurations in azure Ad I am missing? Can you help me with this?

Comment: The issue lies on request used to acquire the first access token. You should put `api://{client id of the Web API app}/.default` for the `scope`.

Comment: Hi Allen, I should Put api://{client id of the Web API app}/.default in SPA app or Web API app?

Comment: You should put it in SPA app.

Comment: I went to my SPA app - Expose an API - Add Scope - right side one popup came to enter scope name and below api://22800555-7031-499a-b04a-acfa27b04f39/ this line is there. Here 22800555-7031-499a-b04a-acfa27b04f39 is client id of SPA app. How can I change this to  api://{client id of the Web API app}/.default? I have added image for reference

Comment: You should expose an API in Web API app. And add it (the exposed API) as permission in SPA app.

Comment: hi Allen Still I am getting app id of SPA in aud field. I have added above three images first one is TodoListAPI API Permission, TodoListAPI  Expose API and TodoListSPA API Permissions. Do you see still any configurations mismatching here

Comment: Please show your code where configures the `scope`.

Comment: Hi Alen, I have added react code above I think I am using react-adal and in that code I am not specifying scope looks like. May I know in above code how can I configure scope? I have added full code above

Comment: I think it should be configured in the `adalConfig` where you set the client id. So how is the `adalConfig` like? And adal seems to use v1.0. So maybe there is a field named `resource`, which means the scope.

Comment: Hi Allen I am using below library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adal.  I dont see scopes they have mentioned here but something they have mentioned endpoints in adalConfig. Is this related to scope?

Comment: I think you are correct. Just put it like this: `endpoints: {
    api: '{client id of the Web API app}',
  },`   Don't add `.default` because it's using v1.0.

Comment: Hi Allen Tried all way but doesnt work. Is there any way I can get token using postman or any other way? but If postman how can I give reply url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230063/discussion-between-allen-wu-and-mr-perfect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the access token is for your web API app, you need to specify the scope as `api://{client id of the Web API app}/.default` for V2.0.

Then the `aud` in access token whill be `{client id of the Web API app}`.

You can get the access token in Postman like this:

[image]

In my experience, adal is using V1.0 so we don't need to put `.default`. You should specify the scope in the `adalConfig` like:

```
export const adalConfig = {
  tenant: '{tenant id}',
  clientId: '{client id}',
  endpoints: {
    api: '{client id of the Web API app}',
  },
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
};
```

Here is [a sample](https://www.appfoundry.be/blog/authentication-with-adal-in-react-single-page-applications) for your reference.